# Copy only specific subdirectories and their contents to another directory

Tags: windows, powershell, filesystems

In the project directory structure attached below, I am attempting to copy only the subdirectories for January, i.e. `Product1_2022-01` and `Product2_2022-01`, including the files contained within them, to the `2022-01` folder located in the Archive. However, although the subdirectories (and contents) are copied as desired, the February files in the `Product1` and `Product2` directories one level up, i.e. files `fileA-02` and `fileB-02`, are also copied.

Is it possible to copy only the subdirectories and their contents? I have included the code to reproduce the above scenario. I am new to PowerShell, so any help or advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

[Directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rs862.png)

Code:

```
$source = @("C:\Product\Testing\Tested\Product1\*",
            "C:\Product\Testing\Tested\Product2\*"
           )
$destination = "C:\Archive\2022\2022-01"

Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $destination -Recurse
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're explicitly telling it to copy the entire contents of `Product1\*`, and `Product2\*`. If you're looking to narrow it down to just the the subfolders either specify the whole path (`Product1\Product1_2022_01`), or just part of the path (`Product1\Product*`):

```
$source = @("C:\Product\Testing\Tested\Product1\Product*",
            "C:\Product\Testing\Tested\Product2\Product*"
           )
$destination = "C:\Archive\2022\2022-01"

Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $destination -Recurse
```

Comment: That has worked a treat, thank you! Unfortunately, I am new to the site, and seem to be unable to upvote your answer.

Comment: Happy to help. Once you get enough points, you will be able to upvote.